# How to loop through options in a drop down list?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to loop through the options or items of a drop down menu, but I don't know the number of items as it will be changeable every time.

Here's the html part of the sList3

```html
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Dschool" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Dschool\',\'\')', 0)" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Dschool" style="font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold;width:500px;">
 <option selected="selected" value="0"> Select From Menu </option>
 <option value="311223">first option</option>
 <option value="311625">some option</option>
</select>
```

Here's my code that I have started

```
For i = 1 To 4
    Set sList1 = .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Dedara").AsSelect
    sList1.SelectByIndex i
    .Wait 2000
    Set sList2 = .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Drel").AsSelect
    sList2.SelectByIndex 1
    .Wait 2000
    Set sList3 = .FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Dschool").AsSelect

    'How can I loop through the options (unknown in length)
Next i
```

I would like to loop each option and debug.print the value of the option.

### SOLUTION

With the help of JeffC this is the final solution

```
            For j = 1 To sList3.Options.Count
            Debug.Print sList3.Options(j).Text
        Next j
```

Comment: I think you can `for each` through the `sList3.children()` or something to that effect? That's how it works with an `HtmlDocument` iirc

Comment: I tried `For Each e In sList3.Children()` but didn't work and I got an error.

Comment: Is there no `Options` list hanging off the `.AsSelect`? If nothing else, you could count the number of `OPTION`s that are children of the `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't get what you mean? Can you give me line of code to count the options as I noticed some of those lists are empty and with no options ..

Comment: I don't do VBA Selenium ... I use C# (and formerly Java). In C#, we have `new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(...)).Options` which is a list of elements. You can slap a `.Count` on the end of that and get the number of options. I don't know if you have the equivalent in VBA but I'm assuming you do since you have a `.AsSelect`. If I were to guess, it would be something like `.FindElementById(...).AsSelect.Options`. If you have Intellisense, when you type `.` after `.AsSelect` you should get a list of methods/properties. Look through that list and see what you can find.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it work by using `Debug.Print sList3.Options.Count` . Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selector to get collection of the options under the parent id

```
Dim elements As Object, element As Object
Set elements = driver.FindElementsByCss("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Dschool option")
```

Then loop

```
For Each element In elements:
    Debug.Print element.text
Next
```

---

CSS:

[image]

---

If the id is dynamic switch css to

```
[id^=ContentPlaceHolder1] option
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. At this line `Set elements ...` I got error of doesn't support this object. And I can't find findElementsByCssSelector method in excel VBA for selenium.. I have played around it and get it work using `FindElementsByCss' instead of `findElementsByCssSelector `

Comment: Sorry I got confused with python syntax and did a sort of hybrid. lol. Let me update

Comment: You know you can also post your own answer and accept after two days.

Comment: But this was JeffC's answer and I just followed his steps

Comment: Up to you but may be useful for other readers and comments can fade away over time. Css selectors will be faster as will For Each loop but your solution is valid.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use for each loop

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_Dschool']"));
Select select = new Select(selectElement);
List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
for (WebElement we : options) 
{
  System.out.println("Element="+we.getText());
}
```

Comment: Ok.. I don't do VBA selenium..I use selenium WebDriver in Java

Comment: I think the solution posted in my post is similar to that used in Java. Am I right?